# Dynamic Shape Creation(Processing)

Tags: math, image-processing, processing

I'm trying to create a program that creates a custom pattern. I have it so that if sides = 3, it's a triangle 4 = rect and anything else above that has a formula so that, if you really wanted, you could have 25 sides. I'm using lines, rotation and rotation to plant, turn, draw repeat.

```
 angleMeasure = (180 * (sides-2) ) /sides;
 println(angleMeasure);
 println(radians(angleMeasure));
 //creating the 5+ shape
 pushMatrix();
 translate(width/2, height/2); //translating the whole shape/while loop

 while(counter < sides){

   line(0,0,170,0);
   translate(170,0);//THIS translate is what makes the lines go in the direction they need too.
   rotate(angleMeasure);

 counter = counter + 1;
```

This works almost correctly. The last and first lines don't connect. Suggestions? Maybe it's a problem with the math, but println reveals a correct angle measure in degrees. Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwYMj.png

EDIT: Changed the rotate from rotate(angleMeasure) to rotate(angleMeasure * -1). This rotated the whole shape and made it clear that the angle on the very first line is off. See:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1KmY.png

Comment: could you upload an image with 4 sides?

Comment: Could you please try again with `rotate(radians(angleMeasure));`? All angle inputs in processing are expected to be in radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to turn by `angle=360°/sides`. And convert this angle into radians.

Thus for a pentagram you need `angle=72°`. The number you computed is 108, which interpreted as radians is 34 full turns plus an angle of about `67°`. This falls `5°` short of the correct angle, so that you obtain a somewhat correct picture with slightly too wide inner angles, resulting in the gap (and not a crossing as when the angle were larger than the correct angle).